# Почему поля класса следует делать закрытыми?

Tags: ооп, классы, php

Почему считается, что делать поля класса открытыми - плохая практика?

Comment: public? да?

Comment: @exec, да, под открытыми я имел в виду `public`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Постараюсь пояснить безотносительно языка программирования, но на примере.

Пусть имеется класс, реализующий абстрактный тип данных стек, то есть хранилище, обмен данными с которым осуществляется по принципу LIFO (последний вошел - первый вышел). Для абстрактного стека должны быть реализованы три операции: pushItem (добавить элемент на вершину стека), popItem (снять элемент с вершины стека) и isEmpty (проверить, пуст ли стек).

Предположим, для хранения элементов стека мы использовали массив, но оставили его публично доступным и это известно программисту, использующему этот класс. Тогда возможны, как минимум, две проблемы:

1. Программист вместо предложенного API будет использовать массив напрямую, нарушая логику работы со стеком (обращаться к элементам стека, минуя вершину; снимать или записывать элементы, не изменяя указатель вершины и т.п.). Ясно, что это может привести к печальным последствиям.
2. При последующей модификации самого класса стека, например, замене массива на другую структуру данных, программисту, завязанному на текущую реализацию, придется переписывать и свой код. Защищая поля данных и некоторые методы, Вы оставляете себе свободу маневра для будущих безболезненных (при условии сохранения API) модификаций. Программист, используя Ваш код как черный ящик, тоже себя страхует и избавляет себя от лишней головной боли по изучению Вашего кода, ему достаточно знать интерфейс (как в старом анекдоте про колбасный цех - кидаешь с этой стороны барана, достаешь с той стороны палку колбасы).

Comment: Спасибо. Эти 2 пункта я, в принципе, знал более-менее.
Мне вот что не ясно: ведь можно сделать поля открытыми и нормальный программист всё равно будет работать через API. А если программист хочет лезть напрямую, он же может просто изменить в коде `private` на `public`. Какие-то странные ограничения)

Comment: Не всегда так легко поменять private на public. Особенно в компилируемых языках.
Хотя товарищи-извращенцы всегда придумают, как обойти код.

Comment: это вы про инкапсуляцию что ли сейчас сказали?

Comment: @Construct, лучше не испытывать судьбу и не надеяться на "нормальность" программистов. Они встречаются гораздо реже, чем хотелось бы. Например, прошлой осенью вдруг в некоторых линуксах перестал корректно работать flash-плейер. Оказалось, в glibc разработчики применили оптимизацию, изменившую внутреннее поведение стандартной функции memcpy, копирующей содержимое одной области памяти в другую. В стандарте и мануалах написано черным по белому: функция работает правильно, если области не перекрываются, в противном случае следует использовать memmove. Но быдлокодеры из Adobe понадеялись на авось.

Comment: Они не понадеялись. Они знали, что делают. Просто они рассчитывали на типичное поведение при копировании (сорцы смотрели). А после оптимизаций, с которыми им помог Интел (а кто ещё знает хорошо процессоры Интел, как не они), порядок копирование байтов стал не очевиден:)

Вывод - к реализации привязываться нельзя!

Comment: Ну в-общем понятно, спасибо. Да, я же пишу на PHP, а есть и компилируемые языки, я забыл))